# How can I read articles by famous scientists for free?

Tags: special-relativity

I am high school student. I want to read the articles of famous scientists. These articles must be in their original language and not edited in any way. For example, I want to read Special Relativity, which was published by Einstein in 1905. In the German language and with an exact copy from 1905. Where can i find this article? I found a few sites(gutenberg project, libgen, sci-hub). But I don't know if these sites provide what I want. Can you guide me?

Comment: this is not what you're looking for, but maybe it can be of interest: https://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/

Comment: My first thoughts are an online University Library. For example UCL library here: @ https://www.ucl.ac.uk/library/using-library/libraries-and-study-spaces/ucl-science-library . You may need to get permission from the university to obtain the original science papers. If you are at high school you could ask your physics teacher or librarian how to do it.

Comment: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/andp.19053221004

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics as a natural science.

Answer (score 4):

Einstein published in German Annalen der Physik, look this up in wiki
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annalen_der_Physik and you find most of his german work free to download. for other authors go to there name in wiki and look up the biblographie and the journals they published in .